# Pygame surface with alpha not blitting transparency

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm trying to make a user interface thing transparent in my game when the mouse isn't hovering over it. But for some reason, when I set the alpha value of the image for it to become transparent, nothing happens. Here is some runnable code for it that replicates the problem:

```
import pygame
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img = pygame.image.load("ink_bar_solid.png")
        self.img.set_alpha(0)
        self.ink_bar_rect = self.img.get_bounding_rect()
        self.x, self.y = 0, 10

resolution = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos
ink_bar = UI()
run = True

def mouse_over():
    if ink_bar.ink_bar_rect.collidepoint(mouse()):
        ink_bar.img.set_alpha(255)
    else:
        ink_bar.img.set_alpha(0)

while run:
    mouse_over()
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit(ink_bar.img, (ink_bar.x, ink_bar.y))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            break
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Edit: I got a comment from someone who said they used their own image and it worked fine... I'm getting this warning when I execute the program:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Is the reason why it doesn't blit properly because of my file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is simply that you're incorrectly blitting your `ink_bar`. Just remove the `self.` in front of each variable name (`self.` is what you use from within the object to refer to itself) like so `(ink_bar.x, ink_bar.y)` in your blit call. After that small modification (and using a 256 by 256 image I loaded myself), the object is invisible when not hovered over, and vice-versa.

Comment: Sorry the selfs in the positional argument were typos. Originally I had it as (0, 0) but changed it to the image's positions here for clarification. The problem still oddly persists for me regardless what goes in the positional argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set_alpha` method doesn't seem to work for unconverted png files. Calling the [`convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) method will also improve the blit performance drastically:

```
self.img = pygame.image.load("ink_bar_solid.png").convert()
```

It also doesn't work for per-pixel alpha surfaces (surfaces converted with `convert_alpha` or created with the `pygame.SRCALPHA` flag). The alpha of per-pixel surfaces can be changed by filling them with a transparent white color and passing the `pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT` special flag, e.g.:

```
image = pygame.image.load('an_image.png').convert_alpha()
# Make a copy so that the original doesn't get modified.
transparent_image = image.copy()
transparent_image.fill((255, 255, 255, 100), special_flags=pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like it only doesn't work with unconverted png files. It works with jpgs. I need to investigate why that's the case and change the answer.

Comment: Analyzing the source code is a bit too much work for me atm, but maybe the devs know why pngs have to be converted. Here's the mailing list: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/info